# Excel formula to define groups for unique items

Tags: excel

Currently at my workplace, I am facing an issue of grouping items. As shown in the image, I need to group the first group of RIOs in a cabinet as 1 and the second group of RIOs in that same cabinet as 2. The process is the same for different cabinets.

Is there a way to get this done by using Excel formula? I don't mind creating extra columns for rough works. It should be noted though that the formula need to work in a table format.

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you show how your result will look like.

Comment: Hi Mrig, Sorry for being unclear about my question. The result that I want to achieve will need to be in the form in "Group" Column where in 1 cabinet, the first group of RIO will need to be defined as 1 and the second group of RIO will need to be defined as 2.

Comment: Based on the screenshot you've provided it looks like you could just test whether the last character in column A is Odd or even. Is that correct?

Comment: @Mrig: You can view the Screenshot by clicking in the "Example" Text. Sorry for inconvenience, this is my first post in the site.

Comment: @TonyM: Hi Tony, Thanks for your suggestion. The RIO list is huge and sometime the last character in column a does not follow the odd or even rules.

Comment: What is the basis for assigning the groups in column C?

Comment: Basically, I will need to indicate that if the RIO is the first unique item in the cabinet, put 1 in column C. If the RIO is the second unique item in the cabinet, put 2 in column C.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If I understood your problem correctly then following should help. (Using helper column)

In `Cell C3` and `Cell D3` write `1`

Then in `Cell C4`  enter the following formula

```
=IF(B3=B4,C3,C3+1)
```

And in `Cell D4` enter

```
=IF(C3=C4,IF(A3=A4,D3,D3+1),1)
```

drag/copy down both formulas as required. See image for reference.

[image]

Note : For this solution to work `Category` column should be sorted.